# Returning the value from a nested function within a callback in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, closures, mean-stack

```
function(Model, payload) {
    try {
        var Obj = new Model(payload);
        Obj.save(function(err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('should be err', err.err);
                retVal = err.err;
            } else {
                console.log('should be user', obj);
                retVal = obj;
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
    return retVal;
};
```

I am trying to return `retVal` from the code snippet above, but I keep getting `undefined` as the return value. When I moved the declaration of `retVal` outside the function to the `global` scope, it somehow manages to work. 
The problem is I don't want to have `retVal` declared globally. Any help?

Comment: IMHO, catching an exception to return it is not a good practice. This will lead you to further problems. If you want to deal with the exception at a higher level, you simply may not want to catch it in your current function.

Answer (score -1):

Declare retVal in the scope of the function at least.

```
function (Model, payload) {
  var retVal;
  ...
  ...
  return retVal;
};
```

Comment: The callback worked!